# Type mismatch when attempting to insert additional rows

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add 9 new rows above my first row but am running into a type mismatch with the code below:

```
wsSheet.Rows("1, 10").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrgin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

I think it's something easy that I'm missing.

I defined wsSheet as a worksheet and can provide more code if necessary.

Comment: `wsSheet.Range("1:10").Insert xlDown, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove`

Comment: or `.Rows("1:10")`, but not `.Rows("1, 10")`